# push to url according to id (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

new react hooks(typescript) developer here, could somebody suggest on how to implement this: when user has chosen from select option(antd) then the button becomes red and can be clicked, that button should take one to that specific option what he chose (id?) with this?:

```
                  history.push(`/info/${....id}`); ??
```

my code :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Select } from "antd";
import { useHistory, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const { Option } = Select;
  const history = useHistory();

function EventsSection() {
  const anarray = [
    { name: "obama", address: "usa", id: "81" },
    { name: "obama", address: "usa", id: "86" },
    { name: "putin", address: "russia", id: "91" },
    { name: "erdogan", address: "turkey", id: "31" },
    { name: "jebordoq", address: "alien", id: "29" },
  ];

  return (
    <section>
      {/* this button becomes red then we know somebody has clicked something from select options */}
      <button>if i'm red click me</button>

      <Select
        className="senderId"
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        placeholder="Hide Me"
        mode="multiple"
        open={true}
        listHeight={350}
      >
        {anarray.map((item, idx) => (
          <Option
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
            className="options"
            key={idx}
            value={item.id}
          >
            {item.name}
            <br></br>
            {item.address}
            <br></br>
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </section>
  );
}

export default EventsSection;
```

ask me if needed

Comment: You''ll want to use the `onChange` event of the `Select`.  You are allowing them to select multiple options with `mode="multiple"`.  What page do we go to then?  Or should we disallow that?

Comment: If it's a single select then the intermediate button click is not necssary.  You probably just want a list of `react-router-dom` `Link` components that you style.

Comment: i'm using         <Route path="/info">  hashtag in url, or do you have better idea ?

Comment: @LindaPaiste antd gives that functionality that if user is not satisfied of what chose, he can click that x to cancel it, and that button is there a way to continue

Comment: @LindaPaiste could you give an example code ?